# How can I 'span' images in wallpapers.xml

Tags: desktop-background, xml

I'm trying to set up some Backgrounds and wrote a custom xml for that (later on I want to make a custom slideshow of these). The images should span over my dual monitor.

```
$ cat /home/user/.local/share/gnome-background-properties/wallpapers.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE wallpapers SYSTEM "gnome-wp-list.dtd">
<wallpapers>
  <wallpaper>
    <name>Test1</name>
    <filename>/home/user/Bilder/test1.jpg</filename>
    <options>span</options>
    <pcolor>#000000</pcolor>
    <scolor>#000000</scolor>
    <shade_type>solid</shade_type>
  </wallpaper>
</wallpapers>
```

With options set to 'span' Control-Center does only show a black thumbnail. Starting Control-Center from terminal brings up an error:

```
$ gnome-control-center background
(gnome-control-center:7019): background-cc-panel-WARNING **: Unhandled value 'span' for enum 'GDesktopBackgroundStyle'
```

If I set options to 'zoom' everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct value is `spanned` (not `span`), so it should work if you change it to that.

I tested this on my Ubuntu 12.10 system with GNOME 3. It doesn't look very consistent though...